# XSD : Large schema validation

Tags: java, xml, xsd

I am trying to validate xml files against a very large industrial schema using JAXP and SAX Parser. The problem is, it takes very long to validate even a small XML file.

I am running Apache Tomcat 6.0. I tried increasing the heap size to 1024 but that was not of much help.

Any other steps that I can take to improve the speed of validation?

Thanks, 
Gaurav

Comment: Use jvisualvm to positively identify where the time is spent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should post your code here. But what you can do for now is to CACHE the [Schema](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/validation/Schema.html) and re-use it for subsequent validations. [See here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-jaxp13a.html) for how to cache the schema using JAXP.