# How to validate XML against a DTD using java?

Tags: java, xml

I need to parse a bunch of incoming xml documents, they all have the different DTD.
DTD is created by myself. And I want to load it in memory once sothat it will remove the over head to read each time.
How can I load using DOM Parser and use it every time.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go through the **Reducing the Cost of Referencing External Entities** section from [here](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/xml/JavaTechandXML_part3/). It has a tip on how to cache DTD's. If you are starting from scratch then I'd suggest you use XSD. FOllow the below SO post on how to cache xsd

[XSD : Large schema validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532353/xsd-large-schema-validation)